# Jquery.when not performing async ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using jQuery.when to perform different request asynchronously.
The problem is that it seems jQuery.when is waiting each call to finish before running the next one.

The fifth call is waiting takes around seconds to return for example when it takes around second to process when executed alone.

Here is my when call:

```
jQuery.when(search_engine.fetchBucketOne(), search_engine.fetchBucketTwo(), search_engine.fetchBucketThree(), search_engine.fetchBucketFour(), search_engine.fetchBucketFive())
    .done(function(bucket_one_result, bucket_two_result, bucket_three_result, bucket_four_result, bucket_five_result){
        search_engine.bucket_one = bucket_one_result;
        console.log('search_engine.bucket_one');console.log(search_engine.bucket_one);
        search_engine.bucket_two = bucket_two_result;
        console.log('search_engine.bucket_two');console.log(search_engine.bucket_two);
        search_engine.bucket_three = bucket_three_result;
        console.log('search_engine.bucket_three');console.log(search_engine.bucket_three);
        search_engine.bucket_four = bucket_four_result;
        console.log('search_engine.bucket_four');console.log(search_engine.bucket_four);
        search_engine.bucket_five = bucket_five_result;
        console.log('search_engine.bucket_five');console.log(search_engine.bucket_five);
    });
```

Here are the ajax request:

```
fetchBucketOne: function() {
    url_params = search_engine.createSearchParams();
    return ($.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/fetch-bucket-one" + url_params,
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }));
},

fetchBucketTwo: function() {
    url_params = search_engine.createSearchParams();
    return ($.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/fetch-bucket-two" + url_params,
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }));
},

fetchBucketThree: function() {
    url_params = search_engine.createSearchParams();
    return ($.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/fetch-bucket-three" + url_params,
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }));
},

fetchBucketFour: function() {
    url_params = search_engine.createSearchParams();
    return ($.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/fetch-bucket-four" + url_params,
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }));
},

fetchBucketFive: function() {
    url_params = search_engine.createSearchParams();
    return ($.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/fetch-bucket-five" + url_params,
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }));
},
```

Here is a screenshot of network loading result through chrome developper tools:

[image: not async]

Thank you for your help everyone!

Comment: Odd behaviour. I would guess that either there's as rogue `async: false` set somewhere which needs to be removed, possibly globally in `$.ajaxSetup` or perhaps the server itself is configured to restrict connections per user in order to prevent attacks.

Comment: I added async: true to each ajax call and there is no change, i wouldn't be surprised if the server is configured to restrict connections per user. That's an interesting idea, thank's for sharing.

Comment: I think i found where the problem is, i'm doing all this request to my controller where i call the api through curl. I don't directly call the API through the ajax call so i can cache it on my side. I am using php builtin server to do the testing and as it is single threaded it can't handle multiple call at the same time. It will probably be ok on Apache server in production, going to test on preproduction environment.

Comment: Well it's not working on Apache also, as long as i call my php controller instead of extern endpoint, request is not async.

Answer (score 0):

I would process that in another way, my approach would be

```
search_engine.setResult = function(name, result) {
    search_engine[name] = result;
}
var fetchList = [
    {
    name: "bucket_one",
    url: "/fetch-bucket-one",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    successFunction: "setResult",
  },
  {
    name: "bucket_two",
    url: "/fetch-bucket-two",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    successFunction: "setResult",
  }

]

for(i in fetchList)
{
    var fetchItem = fetchLists[i];
    $.ajax({
    url: fetchItem.url + searchengine.createSearchParams(),
    contentType: fetchItem.contentType,
    success: function(data) {
            searchengine[fetchItem.successFunction](fetchItem.name, data);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i need to wait all request to end before i can merge the different results. That's why i'm using jQuery.when, which does what you are doing basically and wait all promised to be resolved.